# Combining Rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I am working on making a dual density map currently in ArcMap.  I've conducted kernel density for my two sets of points, one of which contains incidents, the other residencies.  What I want to do is combine the two densities so that it creates a spectrum where one end represents a high density of incidents and the other end indicates a high density of residencies.

How can I go about doing this?

I've tried using the raster calculator to multiply one density by -1 so it inverts the numbers, but I am having trouble combining the two together so that one density goes from -n to 0 and the second density goes from 0 to n.

I've also looked into a bivariate map, but I do not think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and show what you have and describe how these rasters overlap. What happens if a location has the two extremes, does it become a mean of these too values?